# Detecting when print is complete or canceled

Tags: javascript, css, printing

This is kind of a strange question.

I have script that inserts 0 in blank input fields before print widow appears to preserve styling. However, these 0's need to be removed from the screen when either the print was a success or canceled.

Is there a way to detect when the print was either canceled or was successful? This needs to work in all browsers.

My javascript to insert the 0's looks like this

```
 $('#checkRequestDetails').find('input').each(function(i, obj) {
   if ($(this).val() == '') {
     $(this).val('0')
   }
 });
```

OR is there a better way to just show these 0's just for printing formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the `placeholder` attribute for the `input`. Just set its color to transparent, then make a style to set its color to black or whatever just for print.

`:placeholder` is supported in all major browser, but you might need to include all the vendor prefix versions. for this example I am just using the webkit one. ref: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder

Like this:

```css
input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

@media print {
  input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #000;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="0" />

<input type="text" value="999" placeholder="0" />

<input type="text" placeholder="0" />
```

Run the snippet then right click and hit "Print" and in the print preview you will see the "0".